# How to know charset of character?

Tags: character-encoding

A python script fail when trying to encode a supposed `utf-8` string in `iso-8859-1`:

```
>>> 'à'.encode('iso-8859-1')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0300' in position 1: ordinal not in range(256)
```

How to know wich charset is that character ? When encode it in utf-8:

```
>>> 'à'.encode('utf-8')
b'a\xcc\x80'
```

`a` then `\xcc\x80`. I can fount `\xcc\x80` in http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=768&names=-&utf8=string-literal utf8 table.

But it is `utf-8` ? If it is `utf-8` why `'à'.encode('utf-8')` can't encode this string in `iso-8859-1` ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear where the `'à'` character comes from. In fact, it's a [combining character sequence](http://unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html) and you need to [**normalize**](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) it. Next python script uses [`unicodedata` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html) to self-explain and solve your questions:

```
import sys, platform
print (sys.stdout.encoding, platform.python_version())
print ()

import unicodedata
agraveChar='à'       # copied from your post
agraveDeco='à'       # typed as Alt+0224 (Windows, us keyboard)

# print Unicode names
print ('agraveChar', agraveChar, agraveChar.encode('utf-8'))
for ins in range( 0, len(agraveChar)):
    print ( agraveChar[ins], unicodedata.name(agraveChar[ins], '???'))

print ('agraveDeco', agraveDeco, agraveDeco.encode('utf-8'))
for ins in range( 0, len(agraveDeco)):
    print ( agraveDeco[ins], unicodedata.name(agraveDeco[ins], '???'))


print ('decomposition(agraveChar)', unicodedata.decomposition(agraveChar))
print ('\nagraveDeco normalized:\n')
print ("NFC  to utf-8", unicodedata.normalize("NFC" , agraveDeco).encode('utf-8'))
print ("NFC  to latin", unicodedata.normalize("NFC" , agraveDeco).encode('iso-8859-1'))
print ("NFKC to utf-8", unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", agraveDeco).encode('utf-8'))
print ("NFKC to latin", unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", agraveDeco).encode('iso-8859-1'))
```

**Output**:

```
==> D:\test\Python\40422359.py
UTF-8 3.5.1

agraveChar à b'\xc3\xa0'

à LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH GRAVE

agraveDeco à b'a\xcc\x80'

a LATIN SMALL LETTER A
̀ COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT

decomposition(agraveChar) 0061 0300

agraveDeco normalized:

NFC  to utf-8 b'\xc3\xa0'
NFC  to latin b'\xe0'
NFKC to utf-8 b'\xc3\xa0'
NFKC to latin b'\xe0'

==>
```